# Why is a click handler to delete a table row throwing an error as ‘undefined’?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want to delete a row from the table when I click on the button

```
function submitform(){
  var bdelete = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  bdelete.setAttribute("id", "del");
  bdelete.onclick = delid(this);
  var bdname = document.createTextNode("Delete");
  bdelete.appendChild(bdname);
  td6.appendChild(bdelete);
}
```

and function is `undefined`

```
function delid(rows) {
  var del = rows.srcElement.parentNode.parentNode;
  document.getElementById("info").deleteRow(del.rowIndex);
}
```

also this code in submit form function

[See Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N2Pt.png)

Comment: Please add your html too

Comment: Please do not use images to create a minimal working example. The editor provides a code snippet tool, I suggest using it to create just enough html and javascript to show the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing

```
  bdelete.onclick = function(){delid(this)};
```

with

```
  bdelete.onclick = delid(this);
```

Also Put your custom function above the code which is calling it.

```
function delid(rows) {

        var del = rows.srcElement.parentNode.parentNode;
        document.getElementById("info").deleteRow(del.rowIndex);
    }
  var bdelete = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    bdelete.setAttribute("id", "del");
      bdelete.onclick = delid(this);
    var bdname = document.createTextNode("Delete");
    bdelete.appendChild(bdname);
    td6.appendChild(bdelete);
```

Also if this doesn't solve it. Please post your html too.

Comment: var bdelete button is defined in another function

Comment: The number of code is too large, the " stakoverflow " does not allow it

Comment: @A.RR try using a code snippet to reproduce your issue and add an explanation. What are you trying to do and why doesn't it work?

Comment: I want to delete a row from the table when I click on the button

Comment: if you'r using jquery you can, give class to the button "btndelete' and then 

$(".btndelete").click(function(){
      $(this).parents(".tr").remove();
});

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems.

```
function submitform() {
  //...
  bdelete.onclick = delid(this);
  //...
}
```

First issue is the value of `this`. As written, `this` will be the function object `submitform`. If you meant to pass an event object, `submitform` first needs to receive an event argument so it can pass it along.

```
submit.onclick = submitform;
function submitform (event) {
  //...
}
```

Second issue is how the click event is bound to the delete button. This could be valid if `delid()` returned a function, but more likely this should simply assign the function, bind a new function, or wrap in a new function.

```
bdelete.onclick = delid;                          // assignment
bdelete.onclick = delid.bind(null, event);        // function binding
bdelete.onclick = function () { delid(event); };  // new anonymous function
```

Comment: bdelete.onclick = function () { delid(event) }

Comment: @A.RR good feedback, you're right. Wrapping in a new function is another option.